# Add values to new column from a dict with keys matching the index of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary that for examples sake, looks like

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 4, 'c': 7}
```

I have a dataframe that has the same index values as the keys in this dict.

I want to add each value from the dict to the dataframe.

I feel like doing a check for every row of the DF, checking the index value, matching it to the one in the dict, then trying to add it is going to be a very slow way right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `map` and assign back to a new column:

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 4, 'c': 7}
df = pd.DataFrame({'c':[1,2,3]},index=['a','b','c'])

df['new_col'] = df.index.map(d)
```

prints:

```
   c  new_col
a  1        1
b  2        4
c  3        7
```